# Create variants of hardcoded defines

Tags: c, buffer, microcontroller, avr-gcc

I have a C source code for a microcontroller and I would show you the first part of the header:

```
#define USART_RX_BUFFER_SIZE 256
#define USART_TX_BUFFER_SIZE 256
#define USART_RX_BUFFER_MASK (USART_RX_BUFFER_SIZE - 1)
#define USART_TX_BUFFER_MASK (USART_TX_BUFFER_SIZE - 1)

#if (USART_RX_BUFFER_SIZE & USART_RX_BUFFER_MASK)
#error RX buffer size is not a power of 2
#endif
#if (USART_TX_BUFFER_SIZE & USART_TX_BUFFER_MASK)
#error TX buffer size is not a power of 2
#endif

typedef struct USART_Buffer {
    volatile uint8_t RX[USART_RX_BUFFER_SIZE];
    volatile uint8_t TX[USART_TX_BUFFER_SIZE];
    volatile uint16_t RX_Head;
    volatile uint16_t RX_Tail;
    volatile uint16_t TX_Head;
    volatile uint16_t TX_Tail;
} USART_Buffer_t;

typedef struct Usart_and_buffer {
    USART_t *usart;
    USART_DREINTLVL_t dreIntLevel;
    USART_TXCINTLVL_t txcIntLevel;
    USART_Buffer_t buffer;
    PORT_t *rs485_Port;
    uint8_t  rs485_Pin;
    bool rs485;
} USART_data_t;

uint8_t USART_RXBuffer_GetByte(USART_data_t *usart_data);
bool USART_RXComplete(USART_data_t *usart_data);
void USART_TransmitComplete(USART_data_t *usart_data);
...
```

There are several other functions like this.
Their implementation often use both `USART_data_t` and `USART_Buffer_t`, example:

```
bool USART_TXBuffer_PutByte(USART_data_t *usart_data, uint8_t data) {
    uint8_t tempCTRLA;
    uint16_t tempTX_Head;
    bool TXBuffer_FreeSpace;
    USART_Buffer_t * TXbufPtr;

    if (usart_data->rs485) usart_data->rs485_Port->OUTSET = usart_data->rs485_Pin;
    TXbufPtr = &usart_data->buffer;
...
```

In my actual applications I need to declare a lot of `USART_data_t` structs but only a couple of them require such a big buffer (256 bytes). Most will work with very small ones, like 64 or even 32 bytes.

**I easily run out of memory and all that space is actually unused.**

My goal is find a way to save space.

The dirty way is to clone the whole file, rename *all* the variables/functions in order to have two different versions, say one with the buffers of 256 bytes and another with the buffers of 64 bytes.
But then I also have to change every call in my code, and I would avoid that.

This library is very fast because it works on circular buffers with a size of power of 2 and using the defines above it takes only few clock cycles to do the required math. So I really don't want to rewrite the whole library to use a dynamic allocation of the memory.

Any other idea?

Example of use:

```
USART_data_t RS232B_USART_data;
USART_data_t RS232A_USART_data;

#define RS232B_BUFFER_SIZE                  4
char RS232B_RxBuffer[RS232B_BUFFER_SIZE];
char RS232B_TxBuffer[RS232B_BUFFER_SIZE];

#define RS232A_BUFFER_SIZE                  64
char RS232A_RxBuffer[RS232A_BUFFER_SIZE];
char RS232A_TxBuffer[RS232A_BUFFER_SIZE];

ISR(USARTC1_RXC_vect) { USART_RXComplete(&RS232B_USART_data); }
ISR(USARTC1_DRE_vect) { USART_DataRegEmpty(&RS232B_USART_data); }
ISR(USARTC1_TXC_vect) { USART_TransmitComplete(&RS232B_USART_data); }

ISR(USARTD0_RXC_vect) { USART_RXComplete(&RS232A_USART_data); }
ISR(USARTD0_DRE_vect) { USART_DataRegEmpty(&RS232A_USART_data); }
ISR(USARTD0_TXC_vect) { USART_TransmitComplete(&RS232A_USART_data); }

// ...

USART_InterruptDriver_Initialize(&RS232B_USART_data, &RS232B_USART, USART_DREINTLVL_LO_gc, USART_TXCINTLVL_LO_gc, false);
USART_Format_Set(RS232B_USART_data.usart, USART_CHSIZE_8BIT_gc, USART_PMODE_DISABLED_gc, false);
USART_RxdInterruptLevel_Set(RS232B_USART_data.usart, USART_RXCINTLVL_HI_gc);
USART_Baudrate_Set(&RS232B_USART, 2094, -7);
USART_Rx_Enable(RS232B_USART_data.usart);
USART_Tx_Enable(RS232B_USART_data.usart);

USART_InterruptDriver_Initialize(&RS232A_USART_data, &RS232A_USART, USART_DREINTLVL_LO_gc, USART_TXCINTLVL_LO_gc, false);
USART_Format_Set(RS232A_USART_data.usart, USART_CHSIZE_8BIT_gc, USART_PMODE_DISABLED_gc, false);
USART_RxdInterruptLevel_Set(RS232A_USART_data.usart, USART_RXCINTLVL_HI_gc);
USART_Baudrate_Set(&RS232A_USART, 2094, -7);
USART_Rx_Enable(RS232A_USART_data.usart);
USART_Tx_Enable(RS232A_USART_data.usart);
```

Comment: @AlexF the intended use of the library (Atmel's app note) is to have one instance of `USART_data_t` for each USART available. Some devices have up to 8 USARTs.

Comment: This is because each UART needs to have it's own and independent buffer and logic.

Comment: Since C99, C supports _flexible array members_ for structs, i.e. an array member can be declared "open" if it is the last member of the struct. If you would be able to rearrange your data structures in a way that these would only have one `buffer` per struct (i.e. essentially having a `USART_receive_buffer` and a `USART_send_buffer` instead of just one single `USART_buffer`), you should probably be able to use that feature.

Comment: @vlad_tepesch didn't I say that this would need separating the buffers into two structures?

Comment: @mfro sry - nevermind

Answer (score 1):

You could potentially rewrite USART_Buffer_t to contain just a pointer to the rx/tx buffers and add two additional variables that are set to the size of the "attached" buffers.

***This is all just written down, so expect typos etc., but I hope you get the idea.:***

```
typedef struct USART_Buffer {
    volatile uint8_t* pRX;
    volatile uint8_t* pTX;
    volatile uint16_t RX_Size;
    volatile uint16_t TX_Size;
    volatile uint16_t RX_Head;
    volatile uint16_t RX_Tail;
    volatile uint16_t TX_Head;
    volatile uint16_t TX_Tail;
} USART_Buffer_t;
```

Then you write a helper function like

```
USART_InitBuffers(USART_data_t data, uint8_t* pTxBuffer, uint16_t sizeTxBuffer, uint8_t* pRxBuffer, uint16_t sizeRxBuffer) {
     data.pRX = pTxBuffer;
     // ... other assignments
}
```

This way, you can specify your arrays of different size for each USART:

```
uint8_t TxData1[100]
uint8_t RxData1[10]
uint8_t TxData2[255]
uint8_t RxData2[50]

USART_Buffer_t data1;
USART_Buffer_t data2;

main() {
    USART_InitBuffers(&data1, TxData1, sizeof(TxData1), RxData1, sizeof(RxData1));
    USART_InitBuffers(&data2, TxData2, sizeof(TxData2), RxData2, sizeof(RxData2));
}
```

In the end, you have to adjust the library functions, to make use of RX_Size and TX_Size instead of using USART_RX_BUFFER_SIZE and USART_TX_BUFFER_SIZE.